# bulma space does not work anymore on text-area after using jquery keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bulma

Hi I am using jquery to toggle css classes for two divs:

```
// toggle display of segmentations with spacebar
$("body").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    // user has pressed space
    console.log("space pressed");
    $("#im_nor").toggleClass("hidestim");
    $("#im_tum").toggleClass("hidestim");
  }
});
```

In a later stage of my program I am using a bulma text-area:

```
<!-- comment -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="labelspacer"></div>
  <label class="surveylabel" for="comment">optional comment</label>
  <textarea
    class="textarea is-primary form-control"
    name="comment"
    id="comment"
    placeholder="e.g. I especially enjoyed watching the stars."
    rows="5"
  ></textarea>
</div>
```

now somehow space keys are disabled when typing content into this comment field. Space keys however work for normal text inputs like this one:

```
<!-- firstname -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="field">
          <div>
            <div class="labelspacer"></div>
            <label class="surveylabel" for="firstname">first name</label>
            <input
              class="input is-primary form-control"
              name="firstname"
              type="text"
              id="firstname"
              placeholder="Chuck"
              aria-required="true"
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

What is going on, how can I fix this? :)

Comment: If you comment out the jQuery logic does it start working?  I guess I'm unclear why you are drawing a conclusion that that logic is disabling the spacebar.

Comment: yes, it does start working. also interestingly it does not seem to be disabled every time but rather something like 90% of the time.